# Как исправить ошибку 405 в flask

Tags: python, flask

У меня есть вот такой код, я пытаюсь запустить его, но мне выдается ошибка 405. Как мне исправить это

```
@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def sav_db():
    json_data = _get_json_data()
    print(json_data)

def _get_json_data():
    json_data = request.get_json()
    return json_data


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="127.0.0.1", port="5012", threaded=True)
```

Comment: Как запрос делаете? Просто открываете страницу в браузере?

Comment: @Ivan Я отправляю get запрос с другого проекта

Comment: у вас написано `@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])`, `POST`, а вы делаете `GET`, отсюда и ошибка

Comment: @Ivan Нет подожди. Я в другом проекте делаю get запрос на url в виде json, а уже здесь, ловлю его с помощью post

Comment: судя по всему у вас нет понимая того, как происходит http-запрос, потому что не совсем понятно, что такое "ловлю его с помощью POST". Тут хорошо расписано https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Overview

Comment: К тому же GET-запрос с телом это моветон

Comment: @Ivan Хорошо, то есть мне нужно принимать json файл через get запрос? А отправлять через post ?

Comment: Нет, нужно отправлять через `POST` и получать через `POST`. Как хотите получать, так и нужно отправлять. И с телом запрос должен быть именно `POST`, в `GET` данные тоже можно при желании передавать, но не желательно.

Comment: Вам нужно отправлять POST-запрос, в теле которого будет ваш json. И принимать POST (что уже вы делаете), где вы будете обрабатывать ваш отправленный json

Comment: Если данные нужно получить с сервиса методом GET, то и на сервисе метод должен быть помечен как GET. Ну и данные должны возвращаться через return, а не печататься через print.

Comment: * сервис в данном случае - тот код, который вы в вопросе привели

Comment: @Ivan Благодарю

Comment: @CrazyElf Благодарю